# How do I read from a chosen PHP session file

Tags: php, apache, http, session-variables, session-state

Is there a solution that allows me to create a session file based on the first request(request is not coming from a browser but contains a unique ID that will be maintained for a given period/session) and then read from this session file on subsequent requests coming from this same user (identified by the unique ID in request)?

I thought that when I set a session_id($id) or session_name($name) on the first request and create a session(ie session file), I will be able to on user's subsequent request identify and read this session file and pick values from it.

Note: These requests are not coming from a browser.

In a web browser, the cookie holds the ID that identifies the session files so values can be picked from it on subsequent requests. But I don't have this available.

EDITED TO ADD CODE LOGIC

```
if($_GET['sequence'] == 0)  // first request
{
    $uniqueID = $_GET['uniqueID'];
    // I thought     this will create a session file with value provided
    session_id("ses$uniqueID");
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['data1'] = $_GET['data'];
}
else // subsequent request
{
    // we should have a session file, so I thought this will fetch it
    $uniqueID = $_GET['uniqueID'];
    session_id("ses$uniqueID");  //;(
    session_start();
    $data = $_SESSION['data1'];
}
// ....`
```

Comment: if they send this unique id for each request, you can do something (i wouldent call it sessions). cheap api, send id with every request

Comment: You have to pass the session id from the user to the server somehow.  Cookies are the way browsers do this.  If you aren't using a browser then you have to build a way.

Comment: @Dagon can you elaborate. Am not sure I get you.

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using to create and modify the session, please?

Comment: You can think as well about implementing https://jwt.io/ in that case.

Comment: ignore "sessions" just use the id that comes with each request to store\retrieve from db or flat file,

Comment: What does the unique ID look like? Are you getting any warnings or errors when the code runs? Please read the first comment on this page and see if it applies to your situation.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php#116836

Comment: @Crossphire, I've actually read that earlier! Thanks.
The unique ID is all digits but may change.
I'm not getting that error though. I'm slowly beginning to accept that I may just have to create a file(named after the unique ID) to store these values.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you do $sess_id = session_id() what do you get? I am trying to see if the ID it ended up using isn't the one you tried to provide.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of using files because it leaves you something to clean up later. You could use memcache to save the data which would let you set a TTL and not have to worry about temp files filling up the server.

Comment: @CrossphireDevelopment, I ended up using a file. I might set up a cron to delete files if they are older than a certain period